# How do I properly remove software from 16.04 using Ubuntu Software centre?

Tags: software-center

I don't seem to be having any luck removing preinstalled software using 16.04's built in software centre.

The experience could best be described as a game of whack-a-mole: I click remove on something, eg. LibreOffice Draw, wait for it to process, then remove something else, eg. Mines.

Bam, LibreOffice Draw is back.

Sometimes I might get a few LibreOffice components installed, sometimes all of them. I wait, and nothing is processing. But sure enough, at some point when I go to uninstall Cheese or something, the whole LibreOffice suite is back. When I go to re-uninstall LibreOffice, Cheese, Mahjong, Mines etc. come back.

Is there a trick to removing software from 16.04's software centre?

This is a fresh install, the only package I've added is Chrome & all my software is up to date (according to ubuntu software + software updater).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have never heard of such a problem, and it sounds very weird to me. This is not an answer to your question, but if you're only looking to remove some software, you may be better off using the command line: Hit Ctrl+Shift+T to open a terminal and type `sudo apt remove <packagename>` in order to remove a package with the name `<packagename>`.

Comment: I’ve had the same problem. As @MalteSkoruppa suggested, using the terminal is the best alternative. In order to uninstall any application, proceed as follows: (1) Press Ctrl+Shift+T to open the terminal. (2) Execute `apt list --installed | grep -i <APPLICATION_NAME>` (or try with parts of the application name only) to find out the package names for the application. (3) Execute `apt-get purge <PACKAGE_NAME> -s` to simulate a removal and see what packages will be removed. If you see lots of packages there, uninstalling the package isn’t safe. (4) Finally run `sudo apt-get purge <PACKAGE_NAME>`